# Custom scrollbar scrolling triggers AutoScroll scrollbars

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I've been using a UserControl to display a list of controls. I initially had `AutoScroll` enabled, and then opted to not using it. I chose against using it as it stood out and simply didn't 'look' good with the controls theme I've been using.

I took a shot at a framework called [MetroFramework](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework), and I've opted to use the `MetroScrollBar` scrollbar control for a vertical scrollbar.

I've fully disabled AutoScroll, and I then decided to implement the Scrollbar. I simply did this by:

```
scbMain.Scroll += (sender, e) => { VerticalScroll.Value = scbMain.Value; };
```

(where `scbMain` is the Scrollbar I'm discussing)

This works, but not as expected. As soon as I scroll, I get a crazy flickering effect from the default scrollbar, as shown [here](https://i.allym.me/u/4adaa7.gif). A longer list has [the same effect, but more pronounced](https://i.allym.me/u/25af05.gif).

I've attempted to hide the existing scrollbars:

```
VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
```

This has had no effect on fixing my issue.

It should be noted: My scrollbar is docked to the right and there're no other container controls within the `UserControl`.

Comment: There is too little information, no code. If you can provide some minimal code that reproduces the flickering it would involve more people in helping you.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's the *only* code I have for the scrolling effect.

Comment: i said *"minimal code that reproduces the flickering"*. The purpose is to run it ourselves

Comment: Sure: I've isolated the code in a [new project and chucked it on GitHub](https://github.com/AlexM-Dev/Scrollbar-Flickering-Example). Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is still present, by the way. I put in a button outside the region of the `UserControl` - it's less noticeable but you can increase its visibility by adding more controls to render.

Comment: 2 observations. The first one is obvious. The flickering on the scrollbar is due to the fact that there are 2 scrollbars, the metro one and the visual studio one. The second observation is that you need to set the correct values for *minimum, maximum and LargeChange* of metro scrollbar. Basically the problem is why your user control adds the default verticall scrollbar

Comment: `Basically the problem is why your user control adds the default verticall scrollbar` exactly. Even though it's been explicitly disabled. :/.

I'll change the minimum/maximum and LargeChange values. How would I dynamically assign these, to appropriate values (respective of controls in the UserControl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. The issue was in this line of code:

```
scbMain.Scroll += (sender, e) => { ----> /*(Here*/ VerticalScroll.Value = scbMain.Value; <---- };
```

You are actully setting the scroll value of your user control, basically you tell the system to invoke the autoscroll property to set the value!

The correct way is to NOT autoscroll the user control but to scroll a container inside eg a panel. So add a panel to your user control. You are going to scroll the panel and all the controls inside it (in this example i will add the button).

```
this.btnExample.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(62, 0);
this.btnExample.Name = "btnExample";
this.btnExample.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 390);
this.btnExample.TabIndex = 1;
this.btnExample.Text = "Out of Bounds";
this.btnExample.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnExample);
this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(270, 391); //the width must fit inside your user control and the height was arbitrary
this.panel1.TabIndex = 2;

this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
this.Controls.Add(this.scbMain);
this.Name = "CtrlScroll";
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(474, 300);
```

The scrolling:

```
public CtrlScroll() {
        InitializeComponent();

        scbMain.Scroll += ( sender, e ) => {
            //Normally the if statement whouldn't be needed but the metro srollbar
            //has a weird behaviour when the scroll value becomes max
            if( scbMain.Value > panel1.Height - this.Height ) {
                panel1.Top = -( panel1.Height - this.Height );
            }
            else {
                panel1.Top = -scbMain.Value;
            };
        };

        int maxVertical = panel1.Height;

        // SmallChange is typically 1%.
        int smallChangeVertical = Math.Max( (int)( maxVertical / 100 ), 1 );

        // LargeChange is one page.
        int largeChangeVertical = this.Height;

        scbMain.Minimum = 0;
        scbMain.Maximum = maxVertical;
        scbMain.SmallChange = smallChangeVertical;
        scbMain.LargeChange = largeChangeVertical;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! I've committed this to the GitHub repo with a few slight tweaks (i.e. hiding the scrollbar, etc.) -- attributed you to the solution of course! You've saved my life, thank you!

Comment: @AlexM. Glad i helped